# How to know when a Retrofit call is finished

Tags: android, web-services, api, retrofit, retrofit2

Is there a way of know when my Retrofit call has finished it's duty? I like know when all the data is received so the code can move on, like starting another activity or use data from the first call to make a second?

Ps.: I'm using an asynchronous request (.enqueue).

**Edit:**

```
getContact(){ 
//Get a contact List from the server    
    Call<List<ModelContact>> callM =  contactInterface.createRContact(listContact);
    callM.enqueue(new Callback<List<ModelContact>>() {
    @Override

    public void onResponse(Response<List<ModelContact>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        // Fetch the List from Response and save it on the local database
        }

    @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Error: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });

    //Gets a object containing some configurations
    Call<Configs> callC = contactInterface.getConfigs(Configs);
    callC.enqueue(new Callback<Configs>() {
    @Override

    public void onResponse(Response<Configs> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        // Fetch the Configs object and save it on the database
        }

    @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Error: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });

    //Here I need to start a new activity after the calls
    Intent loginact = new Intent(TokenActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
           startActivity(loginact);


}
```

Comment: you can provide a delegate to enqueue (aka listener) .

Comment: Where can I find a code sample, I've goggled it and found nothing...

Comment: why don't you post your attempt?

Comment: Posted it, and thanks for the answers

Comment: you want to wait that both calls return before starting the new activity?

Comment: Yes that wold be just fine.

Comment: I've just seen something about RxJava, do you tink it wold be useful in this case using flatMaps?

Comment: RxJava is indeed something I would look into

Comment: I 'm trying since yesterday but wasn' t able to make it work with the flatMap

Comment: RxJava has a huge learning curve,

Comment: @Rafael can you find a solution, I have the same problem :(

Comment: @ysfcyln At the time, i just needed to start another request using the parameters that I've received, so all I did was create another method using them and called it inside the`onResponse()`method making a null verification first.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you can use two boolean flags and start the new intent outside of your getContact method.

Something like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    //lot of code omitted 
    private boolean cIsFinished;
    private boolean mIsFinished;

    private void getContact(){
      //create M and C 
      m.onResponse(){
        //do whatever you want with data and call startIntent
        mIsFinished=true;
        startIntent();
      }
      c.onResponse(){
        //do whatever you want with data and call startIntent
        cIsFinished=true;
        startIntent();
      }


    }
    private synchronized void startIntent(){
       if(cIsFinished && mIsFinished){
          //startIntentHere!
          Intent intent = new blah blah blah
       }

    }    
}
```

Comment: Using this method when the code reaches the startIntent() and the responses haven't been received yet, it wold stop there, I need it to be responsive, like when the variables are set to true, it makes the test again... Any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
//Gets a object containing some configurations
Call<Configs> callC = contactInterface.getConfigs(Configs);
callC.enqueue(new Callback<Configs>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<Configs> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
    // Fetch the Configs object and save it on the database
       Intent loginact = new Intent(TokenActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
       startActivity(loginact);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Error: " + t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

inside `callM`'s `onResponse` method like this. That way firs `callM` will execute, whenever it finishes `callC` will execute, and whenever `callC` finishes it will throw the Intent.

```
getContact(){ 
    //Get a contact List from the server    
    Call<List<ModelContact>> callM =  contactInterface.createRContact(listContact);
    callM.enqueue(new Callback<List<ModelContact>>() {

    @Override    
    public void onResponse(Response<List<ModelContact>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        // Fetch the List from Response and save it on the local database
            //Gets a object containing some configurations
            Call<Configs> callC = contactInterface.getConfigs(Configs);
            callC.enqueue(new Callback<Configs>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<Configs> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                    //Fetch the Configs object and save it on the database
                    //Here I need to start a new activity after the calls
                    Intent loginact = new Intent(TokenActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(loginact);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    Log.i("TAG", "Error: " + t.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Error: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });    
  }
```

Comment: I'm kinda trying not to get in a Callback Hell, because later I'm gona have to do the same thing using 8 different calls, and setting one inside another will get kinda messy... I think

Answer (score 0):

If you have any request depend each other, it'll be complex. You can do that with RxJava by using flatMap method to chain multiple request and avoid callback hell. it's pretty simple. You can learn it here.

http://joluet.github.io/blog/2014/07/07/rxjava-retrofit/

Comment: Reference Link is broken

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some task in another activity or another fragment after finishing retrofit call but your activity has changed and you are still waiting on the retrofit call to finish, you can use interface to send data.

Lets say you've an Activity A which is calling an API via retrofit, while this call is executing user has moved to another Activtiy B and now you need to call a method (or do something else) in Activity B upon the completion of the call from A.

Create an interface AB in A, implement AB and override its method in Activity B and call the method via an object of interface AB in activity A inside onResponse() method of the API call .